# QInputMethod : programatically end the input method session

Tags: qt

I have a QWidget ( lets call it parentWidget ) on which I have enabled the input method by setting the attribute : Qt::WA_InputMethodEnabled.

My interest is to pop up a Line dialog ( lets call it inputMethodEditor ) which should further handle all the input of the text.

Now I have read that the inputMethod works like a session, means it has states like startedToCompose, composing, completing. While the input method is  in startedToCompose or composing state it sends the string under composition in preEditString through inputMethodEvent and once the session completes it sends the final composed string in commitString().

My intent is to finish this session started on parentWidget as soon as the inputMethodEditor dialog is popped up.

So, the question is, whether there is a way to close this session programmatically.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring a while, I could figure it out, I don't know how I overlooked it earlier.
So the trick is to invoke QInputMethod::reset function.
Something like this:

```
QApplication* application = static_cast<QApplication *>(QApplication::instance());
application->inputMethod()->reset();
```